Woocommerce: show 2 columns on mobile for related products
I'm recently using the Blockify Theme for Wordpress and am using Woocommerce.
I would like to show 2 columns for the related products on mobile.
Here's an example URL: https://superveggie.es/producto/tofu-mercadona/
The products at the bottom should show 2 columns in mobile.
By modifying this line of code and adding a "display:flex" to it I manage for the products to not stack up, instead they display one beside the other in a row:
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .wp-block-post-template-is-layout-grid.wp-block-post-template-is-layout-grid.wp-block-post-template-is-layout-grid.wp-block-post-template-is-layout-grid {
grid-template-columns: 1fr;
**display:flex;**
    }
}

The next step I guess would be to assign a 50% width to each product column but this is where I get stuck.
I have also checked this post here but the solution provided is not working for me: woocommerce related products 2 column issues for mobile
Does someone know how I could fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

You need to add flex-wrap: wrap as well, to allow the items to break into multiple rows; and then specify a proper width. Since gap: 20px is also applied to this list, you'll need to reduce the width of the items accordingly, so width: calc(50% - 10px)

@C3roe brilliant! Thanks so much for your fast and efficient help! That worked!! :D
